Solr Restore API gives incorrect response
I have solr cloud version 9.5 with two nodes deployed in kubernetes cluster. I am trying to restore the collection backup using the Solr restore API.
I am experiencing an issue with the Solr backup API. Although the API restores the backup in Solr, it frequently returns an error message instead of indicating success. While the API occasionally responds with success, it mostly returns errors even though the collection backup is restored.
Most of the time, the number of files is correct after the restore despite the error message. However, on one occasion, the number of files was incorrect, I am guessing that the backup was only partially restored, despite the error message being the same.
API:-
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=RESTORE&name=46ba935f-a28a-44e2-ba93-5fa28a94e256&location=file:/var/solr/data&collection=46ba935f-a28a-44e2-ba93-5fa28a94e256
API Response -
{ "responseHeader":{ "status":500, "QTime":3146 }, "error":{ "metadata":["error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException","root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"], "msg":"Could not restore core", "trace":"org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not restore core\n\tat org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrResponse.getException(SolrResponse.java:56)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.admin.api.RestoreCollectionAPI.restoreCollection(RestoreCollectionAPI.java:144)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.admin.api.RestoreCollectionAPI.invokeFromV1Params(RestoreCollectionAPI.java:199)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler$CollectionOperation.lambda$static$33(CollectionsHandler.java:1074)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler$CollectionOperation.execute(CollectionsHandler.java:1264)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler.invokeAction(CollectionsHandler.java:319)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler.handleRequestBody(CollectionsHandler.java:297)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:226)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.handleAdmin(HttpSolrCall.java:932)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.handleAdminRequest(HttpSolrCall.java:880)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:541)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.dispatch(SolrDispatchFilter.java:262)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(SolrDispatchFilter.java:219)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.ServletUtils.traceHttpRequestExecution2(ServletUtils.java:249)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.ServletUtils.rateLimitRequest(ServletUtils.java:215)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:213)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:195)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:210)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:527)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:131)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:598)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:122)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:223)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1580)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:221)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1384)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:176)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:484)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1553)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:174)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1306)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:129)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:149)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.InetAccessHandler.handle(InetAccessHandler.java:228)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:141)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:122)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:301)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:122)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:822)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:122)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:563)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel$RequestDispatchable.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:1598)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:753)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:501)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:287)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:314)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:100)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectableChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectableChannelEndPoint.java:53)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.runTask(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:421)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.consumeTask(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:390)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.tryProduce(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:277)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.run(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:199)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:411)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:969)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.doRunJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:1194)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1149)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)\n", "code":500 } } 
I am using the Solr backup API to perform these backups. Am I doing something wrong?
